# how do we make sure browser uses from its cache instead of downloading js libraries every time we connect the server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, caching, browser-cache

Consider I have have HTML page where I am importing/loading JQuery lib. This HTML invoked by(simple button) other application hence the JQuery lib are downloaded from server for the first time. But after wards the application should be used from browser cache!

But  It's not using from the browser and instead it is downloading every time when the HTML got invoked. even I made it cache option as true in ajax operation!

Fyr, js load script code:
in HTML beginning:

```
<script src="/idcapture/js/jquery-min_1.3.js"></script>

 LoadScript("/idcapture/js/model-b/jquery.min_1.6.js");
function LoadScript(url) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url : url,
        dataType : "script",
        cache : true,
        async : false,
        success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        }
    });
}
```

outcome checked in firefox dev tool and I think it downloading the script each time.

Fyr,

```
http://localhost:8080/idcapture/js/model-b/jquery.min_1.6.js?_=1507559241653    90153 bytes     1   2017-10-09 19:57:21
http://localhost:8080/idcapture/js/model-b/jquery.min_1.6.js?_=1507559323635    90153 bytes     1   2017-10-09 19:58:43
```

Please note that we are using two jquery libs! (And we are working out these through noConflict())

Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `LoadScript` method appears to be adding a timestamp to the path. You need to remove it. Also note that jQuery 1.6 is *very* out of date - over 5 years in fact. You should really update that

Comment: I don't get it. You use LoadScript to load jquery but LoadScript uses jQuery itself... ?

Comment: @Rory: Yes. the jquery outdated one since our application use other components which supports 1... so..

Comment: The browser uses the *entire* URL to manage the cache. That `_` parameter at the end of your URL strings is what's causing the cache to be avoided; because your code is making unique new URLs every time it wants the library, the browser will think that it never has the content in the cache.

Comment: @Salketer: updated question

Comment: @Pointy : Thank you so much. The root cause as is the same you briefed here.   Thanks :)